# Ruby : How to call Derived Class Method in Base Class

Tags: ruby, oop

I want to Access the methods of the Derived class in the parent class. Please advice

```
Class A

 def methodA
 end

 def methodB
 end

end

Class B < Class A

 def methodC
 end

 def methodD
 end

end
```

I want to call methodD inside methodB

```
Class A
 def methodA
 end

 def methodB


 methodD
 end

end
```

Thanks.

Comment: Very strange requirement.. Need to hack :p

Comment: This is actually a standard practice in OOP called [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)). Basically the call to `methodD` by class `A` is not defined at that point in the code; it polymorphs, so to speak, dependent upon which derived class invokes it.

Answer (score 3):

What you wrote works, with some cleanups to the syntax. As long as your object is of the derived class `B`, then it knows what `methodD` is. In contrast, an object of class `A` will throw a `NameError` if you call `methodB` on it, since it doesn't know what `methodD` is.

```
class A

 def methodA
 end

 def methodB
   puts 'Called A#methodB'
   methodD
 end

end

class B < A

 def methodC
 end

 def methodD
   puts 'Called B#methodD'
 end

end

b = B.new
b.methodB
# Called A#methodB
# Called B#methodD
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call the method.

```
class A
  def a
    b
  end
end

class B < A
  def b
    :b
  end
end

B.new.a
# => :b
```

Calling a method sends a message to the receiver, in this case the `:b` message. If the object responds to the message, then everything will just work.

You could also do this:

```
a = A.new

def a.b
  :x
end

a.b
# => :x
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Template Method](http://reefpoints.dockyard.com/ruby/2013/07/10/design-patterns-template-pattern.html) *design pattern*.

```
Class A
 def methodA
 end

 def methodB
 end

 def methodD
  raise NotImplementedError, 'Sorry, you have to override it!'
 end
end

Class B < Class A
 def methodC
 end

 def methodD
  puts "methodD"
 end
end
```

In this scenario, the `methodD` is called a `Hook Method` because basically inform all concrete classes that the method may require an override. The idea is: if the base implementation is undefined the subclasses must define the hook methods.